# How do I open the blinds in this room?

Tags: alexa, ikea-tradfri

I have the following rooms in my house

- Room A
- Room B
- Room C

In those rooms, I have the following Ikea smart blinds.

- Room A: "Room A Blind"
- Room B: "Room B Blind"
- Room C: "Room C Blind"

Each room also has an Amazon Echo Dot. All devices are in the appropriate alexa groups.

When I stand in Room A and say "Open the blinds," Alexa asks me which blinds I mean. Clearly I want the blinds for the room I am standing in, Alexa!

How do I get Alexa to open the blind for the room I speak to?

Comment: If you've already added the dot to the appropriate group, maybe its a matter of using singular instead of plural ! Try "Open the blind". I guess the makers of the english language did not envision the automation difficulties of having the same word be singular or plural !

Comment: Tried that, no difference.

Comment: I don't have actual experience with alexa ... try asking alexa `which room am I in?` or `what is my location?`

Comment: Have you been able to get lights to work correctly with such grouping ? I'm wondering if the issue is with the dot devices not knowing where they are or with the blinds and grouping. @jsotola's suggestion above can help determine whether the dot knows where it is.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop That makes this all the more confusing - the lights *do* turn on in the room I am in when I say "alexa, turn on the lights".

Comment: @jsotola When asked `what is my location?` Alexa just returns my full postal address, not the name of the room that this specific unit is in. When asked `which room am I in?` Alexa returns, "Hmm, I don't know that one."

Answer (score 1):

Alexa rooms only allow for 'turn the lights on/off', not 'close or open shades'. It makes absolutely no sense, but it's been that way for years and likely always will be.